# Path components of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-actions on a manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a closed (compact and no boundary) topological manifold and $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be the group of order two. Let $\mathcal{G}(M)$ be the space of continuous $G$-actions on $M$ (say, with the $C^0$ topology).

**Question 1:** What is $\pi_0(\mathcal{G}(M))$? In other words, how many path components does $\mathcal{G}(M)$ have?

**Question 2:** How does the answer compare in the smooth category (i.e. $M$ is a smooth manifold and all actions are smooth)?

If these questions are intractable in general, how about for special cases of $M$ like $M=S^n$ or $M=\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=dim(M)= 2$ then the answers in topological and smooth categories are  the same. The cardinality of $\pi_0({\mathcal G}(M)$ is finite for $M=S^2$ (two) and $M=RP^2$ (one) but is countably infinite otherwise. For $n\ge 3$ the answers in two categories are different. Already for $n=3$, I think, you have continuum of components of ${\mathcal G}_{top}(S^3)$ (because of wild involutions whose fixed-point sets are wild spheres and wild circles in $S^3$), while ${\mathcal G}_{diff}(S^3)$ has cardinality three, described by conjugacy classes of order 2 subgroups of $O(3)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of any general results on $\pi_0(\mathcal{G}_{diff}(M))$, possibly in higher dimensions? I'd appreciate any references. Thanks

Comment: @smnas For instance, take a look at the book  Lopez de Medrano, "Involutions on Manifolds", 1971. It is a bit old but will more than satisfy your curiosity.  (If anything, it will be probably too hard for you.)

Comment: @smnas If it helps the implicit point here is that your set is the same as equivalence classes of involutions, equivalent if they are conjugate by a diffeomorphism isotopic to the identity. The higher you go in dimension the more wild this will get: there are many many inequivalent involutions already on $S^4$. If you want "free" you then start getting many in dimensions higher than this (see: "fake projective space").